# Not able to connect Laravel application on App Engine to Cloud SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Laravel application running on Google App Engine and I want to connect it to the Google Cloud SQL database I have. I have tried many solutions none of them fixed the problem. Everytime it does a request to the database, it throws 
**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = CQZwtQFAm5RCYcP4ZSqf5mtxTnebGUigQQKVluJa limit 1)**. 
I do have the sessions table, and I also get this error while trying to log in but with the users table then.

I've trying changing up all the environment variables, editing the config/database.php file, ...

Heres my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: mykey
  APP_TIMEZONE: "Europe/Brussels"
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database

  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_DATABASE: data
  DB_USERNAME: root # tried custom user aswell
  DB_PASSWORD: mypassword
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/projectname:region:instancename"

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "projectname:region:instancename"
```

Here is a part of config/database.php (mostly unedited):

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Obviously I want this connection to be succesful. Let me know if you need any more code parts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does your database has a `sessions` table ? if not, you need to run these two commands `php artisan session:table` and `php artisan migrate` to create the table. same thing for the `cache`

Comment: @N69S As mentioned, I do have the table and migrated it aswell :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change this line:

```
cloud_sql_instances: "projectname:region:instancename"
```

into this line:

```
cloud_sql_instances:projectname:region:instancename
```

If that doesn't work, please check [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https:%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.164522367.-1360075521.1510572080) and activate your API if you haven't done so.

Also, if enabling the API didn't solve the issue, please revert the `cloud_sql_instances` variable to having double quotes on the value.

Comment: Thanks, the quotes actually did it! (I suppose as I also enabled the API linked, but I doubt it was due to that)

Comment: @StijnTratsaert glad I've helped. Cheers!