# Laravel deployment to google cloud app engine issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

Thank you in advance,

I am trying to deploy my laravel project into google cloud (APP ENGINE used)
However, I almost did things but unable to connect to the database

when i am migrating tables with `php artisan migrate`, it is showing below error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = demo-db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE
```

my `app.yaml` looks like below

```
runtime: php 
env: flex
runtime_config:
 document_root: public
skip_files:
 - .env
env_variables:
 APP_NAME: Demo
 APP_ENV: local 
 APP_KEY: base64:991ihCoj56qE2RiLqaf+LnBdOBfPzaER2cd4d5d4d4 
 APP_DEBUG : true
 APP_URL: https://demo.ue.r.appspot.com
 CACHE_DRIVER: file

 SESSION_DRIVER: file
 SESSION_LIFETIME: 120
 APP_LOG: daily
 APP_TIMEZONE: UTC

 DB_CONNECTION: mysql
 DB_HOST: DB_HOST
 DB_DATABASE: DB_DATABASE
 DB_USERNAME: DB_DATABASE
 DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
 DB_SOCKET: "DB_SOCKET"

 QUEUE_DRIVER: database

 MAIL_DRIVER: smtp
 MAIL_HOST: smtp.googlemail.com
 MAIL_PORT: 465
 MAIL_USERNAME: MAIL_USERNAME
 MAIL_PASSWORD: MAIL_USERNAME

 LOG_DELETE:  true 
 GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID : GOOGLE_VISION_PROJECT_ID

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: demo-db
```

I have also followed steps of https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-web-app-on-google-app-engine-ecfbb0d49b00

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part:

```
DB_SOCKET: "DB_SOCKET"

beta_settings:
   cloud_sql_instances: demo-db
```

with the following:

```
DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME

beta_settings:
       cloud_sql_instances: YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME
```

where `YOUR_CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME` will be in the format of ***projectname:region:instancename***

You can get this information by navigating to Cloud Console > SQL > Instance connection name

---

Community Tutorial: Laravel PHP - App Engine Flex - Cloud SQL:

- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible

Similar question:

- [Not able to connect Laravel application on App Engine to Cloud SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728725/not-able-to-connect-laravel-application-on-app-engine-to-cloud-sql-database)

Comment: i resolved my issue by changing few things in .env while app.yaml seems fine
now i am getting another issue
laravel generally store sessions data in storage/framework/sessions but we have set /tmp for the same, so i checked /tmp but there is no datas into /tmp

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed. Feel free to post your solution, so other community users reading this can also benefit from your answer. Now, in regards to your new issue, a whole new issue may warrant a new Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB_DATABASE: DB_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME: DB_DATABASE
DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
```

Just adding only the above statements and removed the rest works for me in `.env`